# Private and public Knowledge Base

Tags: authentication, knowledge

We want to develop two knowledge bases hosted on force.com sites. One will be the public one (authenticated within our private web domain) and the private one that should be accessible only by Salesforce users. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two Article Types and, via Profiles, control who can see what Article Types.